# How to convert a JSON dictionary to a list of values?

Tags: javascript, json

I have following JSON string:

```
{"Local People":{"label":"Local People","data":1},"Student":{"label":"Student","data":1}}
```

I want to convert it to the following:

```
[{
    "label" : "Student",
    "data" : 1
},
{
    "label" : "Student",
    "data" : 1
}]
```

I have tried it many times but I've been unsuccessful. Please help!

Comment: really twice `"label" : "Student"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you have parsed the string with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), you could take the keys of the object and iterate over the properties for a new array with the items.

```js
var JSONstring='{ "Local People": { "label": "Local People", "data": 1 }, "Student": { "label": "Student", "data": 1 } }'
    object = JSON.parse(JSONstring),
    array = Object.keys(object).map(function(k) {
        return object[k];
    });

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nina. Now its done. saved my time.

Comment: ES2015 for the win : 
var array = Object.values(JSONstring);